# Slicing memory views with a list of indices

Tags: python, numpy, cython, slice

I am sure this is a duplicate, but I really couldn't find the answer elsewhere.

My primary problem is that I'm using numpy boolean indexing in my code and I'm optimizing it.

I do something like:

```
y_ind = ~isnan(y)
otheThing = y[t,y_ind[t,:]]
```

The reason I save this slice in `otherThing` is because I use it for several computations, so that I avoid reslicing it every time.

My solution was to use memory views instead of `np.ndarray` for `y` and `otherThing`.

The problem is that boolean indexing doesn't work in cython, so that I'm trying to slice it with a list of integers. Just like we would do in numpy, something like:

```
x = np.random.randn(5,5)

array([[-0.56313056, -1.27834803, -0.30052179, -2.00063006, -2.05059544],
       [-0.44563071, -0.63580159, -0.67538499, -0.9192516 ,  0.49663121],
       [ 2.11943794, -0.51746142, -0.80092609, -0.89391932,  1.91359607],
       [ 0.52593344, -0.59931707,  0.78093441, -1.62449658, -1.65887717],
       [-0.46422764,  0.96595406, -0.47142008, -0.28886925, -1.86674776]])

x[2,[1,2]]

array([-0.51746142, -0.80092609])
```

What happens when we try to do that is something like:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t,ndim=2] a = np.random.randn(n,n)
cdef double[:,:] a_mv = a
print(np.array(a_mv[5,(1,3)]))

.pyx:30:27: Invalid index for memoryview specified, type (long, long)
In [22]:
```

Is it possible ? is there a better approach ?

Comment: I'd edit the question to highlight the `cython` issue, maybe even including a working `cython` function.

Comment: Someone down voted the question without explaining why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the underlying numpy array from a memoryview with `.base` so you could do

```
otheThing = y.base[t,y_ind[t,:]]
```

(The same would work for your "list of integer indices").

Cython memoryviews are pretty restricted in how you can index them - it's really just integers and slices. They're designed to be a fast way to get access to the memory rather than a full-featured array class.

It isn't possible to get a speed-up from Cython when slicing things this way so if this is all you're doing with the memoryview then there's no benefit to typing it - just leave it as an untyped Python object. (You may be doing something useful with it beforehand of course though)